# javascript function inside jquery foreach loop doesn't wait for response

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, foreach

My foreach loop:

```
jQuery(".custom-checkbox").each(function() {
      if (jQuery(this).attr('data-action') == 'true') {

      if(deleteQuoteItemFromListing(jQuery(this).attr('data-id'))){
                    console.log('passed');
            }else{
                    console.log('failed');
            }
      }    
 });
```

And the function is(It's using prototype) but it successes

```
function deleteQuoteItemFromListing(id){
    //does someoperations and on success
    delurl = getDelUrl()+id; //baseurl/module/action/delete/id
    new Ajax.Request(delurl,{
        method: 'get',
        onSuccess: function(transport){
            return TRUE;
        } 
    })
}
```

but the problem is all foreach executes at once, and doesn't wait for response from function. It prints `failed` even the operation is success.

**Updated**

The other way round i tried first is this

```
jQuery('.delete-from-quote').click(function() {
        var i = 0, j = 0;
        jQuery(".custom-checkbox").each(function() {
            if (jQuery(this).attr('data-action') == 'true') {
                i++;
            }
        });


        if (i == 0) {
            alert('please choose product');
            return false;
        }

        jQuery(".custom-checkbox").each(function() {

            if (jQuery(this).attr('data-action') == 'true') {

                var urlData = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('qquoteadv/index/delete/'); ?>";
                urlData += "id/" + jQuery(this).attr('data-id') + "/"

                var ajax = jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: urlData,
                    success: function(msg) {
                        j++;
                    }
                })

            }
          if(i==j){location.reload();} //after completing all, reload the page
        });
  });
```

The problem is to know all action completed and reloading the page.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that the code you've omitted is doing an asynchronous ajax call. Since ajax is asynchronous by default, the code you write there (`$.ajax` or whatever) *starts* the process, but then the process continues in the background while your code continues to run.

There's no reasonable way to make the `deleteQuoteItemFromListing` function *wait* for the response. (While it's possible to do *synchronous* ajax, A) it makes for a poor user experience by locking up the browser UI, and B) jQuery will be removing that option at some stage, forcing you to go direct to XHR if you want to keep doing it.)

Instead, restructure your code to embrace the asynchronous nature of web programming by having your function either return a promise or accept a callback, and then resolve the promise or call the callback when done.

Here's a rough idea of what the promise version would look like:

```
jQuery(".custom-checkbox").each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).attr('data-action') == 'true') {
        deleteQuoteItemFromListing(jQuery(this).attr('data-id'))
            .done(function(id) {
                console.log(id + ' passed');
            })
            .fail(function(id) {
                console.log(id + ' failed');
            });
    }    
});

function deleteQuoteItemFromListing(id){
    var d = jQuery.Deferred();
    jQuery.ajax(/*...*/)
        .done(function() {      // This bit assumes the deletion worked if
            d.resolveWith(id);  // the ajax call worked, and failed if the
        })                      // ajax call failed; if instead the ajax
        .fail(function() {      // call always works and returns a flag,
            d.rejectWith(id);   // adjust accordingly
        });
    return d.promise();
}
```

Comment: Yes there is ajax call made on the function.

Comment: @K.C.: You'll want to update the question to show that, but I've actually guessed right, so this answer addresses that.

Answer (score 2):

Using callback ensures that the function is executed.

```
jQuery(".custom-checkbox").each(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).attr('data-action') == 'true') {
        deleteQuoteItemFromListing(jQuery(this).attr('data-id'), handleData);

    }
});

    function handleData(data) {
    if (data) {
        console.log('passed');
    } else {
        console.log('failed');
    }
}


function deleteQuoteItemFromListing(id, callback) {
    //does someoperations and on success
    delurl = getDelUrl() + id; //baseurl/module/action/delete/id
    new Ajax.Request(delurl, {
        method: 'get',
        onSuccess: function (transport) {
            callback(true);
        }
    })
}
```

I hope this will work for you. you need to define handleData function outside of the other function.

Comment: The callback function doesn't trigger

Comment: @K.C. I gave you an idea, its not necessary will run, you can debug your code further. ;)

Answer (score 1):

(Part of) Your problem is in this simple statement:

```
return TRUE;
```

In JavaScript, the "true" boolean is written in lowercase:

```
return true;
```

The interpreter thinks `TRUE` is a variable, and will throw a `ReferenceError`, since it's not set / defined anywhere, meaning the function will never return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery When.

You need to queue those Deferred in an array of Deferred and then apply all of the functions at once.

If one fails all will fail and if all succeeds all will pass.

check this out [jQuery When](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

```
      var queue = [];
      var items = 0;
      return new $.Deferred(function (deferred) {
      $(".custom-checkbox").each(function () {
       if ($(this).attr('data-action') == 'true') {
        items++;
        queue.push(function () {
            new Ajax.Request(delurl, {
                method: 'get',
                onSuccess: function (transport) {
                    items--;
                    if(items === 0)
                        deferred.resolve();
                },
                onError:function(e){
                  deferred.reject(e);   
                }
            });
        });
    }
});

//now resolve all of the deferred fns

  $.when(queue).done(function(){
      console.log('All went well');
  })
 .fail(function(e){
      console.log('Error ' + e);
  });
});
```